# Array numbers changes to random numbers

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm beginner on C programming and cant solve the problem.I'm trying to print a random generated binary tree to output console and delete some leaf's if its wanted.After deletion,i need to adjust binary tree without that number so what i did was i deleted number from array and tried to call main function to crate a binary tree with new array.

But when i recall main function for to make new binary tree,array becomes something like this but different every time:

```
223412224   1195327832   4200751   0   -1921113323   30818502   -276547975   32767   0
```

But it should be like this:

```
7 1 9 4 5 3 8 12 34
```

What can be the problem ? I can't figure it out.
(When i try to print new array before calling main funtion again,it prints correctly)

Code :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int count=4;
int kat=20;
int number=10;
int onetime=1;
struct bin_tree {
int data;
struct bin_tree * right, * left;
};
typedef struct bin_tree node;

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->right = temp->left = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }

}

node* search(node ** tree, int val)
{
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if(val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
}

int getLevelCount(node *tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int leftMaxLevel = 1 + getLevelCount(tree->left);
    int rightMaxLevel = 1 + getLevelCount(tree->right);
    if (leftMaxLevel > rightMaxLevel)
    {
        return leftMaxLevel;
    }
    else
    {
        return rightMaxLevel;
    }
}

void printLevel(node *tree, int level)
{
    int space;
    space=kat*count;
    int i;
    if (tree != NULL && level == 0)
    {
    for (i=kat; i < space; i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%d", tree->data);
    kat=kat-2;
    }   
    else if (tree != NULL)
    {
        printLevel(tree->left, level - 1);
        printLevel(tree->right, level - 1);
    }

}

void printElements(node *tree)
{
    int i;
    int levelCount = getLevelCount(tree);
    for (i = 0; i < levelCount; i++)
    {
        printLevel(tree, i);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void deltree(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        deltree(tree->left);
        deltree(tree->right);
        free(tree);
    }
}

int RandomNumberGenerator(int value)
{
    int i,out;
    out=rand() % 101;
    return out; 
}

int menu(int islem){
    int secim,sil;
    printf("do you wish to delete a number from tree\n");
    printf("1-yes\n");
    printf("0-no\n");
    scanf("%d",&secim);
    if (secim==1){
        printf("Enter the number you want to delete: \n");
        scanf("%d",&sil);
        return sil;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random_numbers[number];
    int i,islem,pos;
    node *root;
    node *tmp;
    root = NULL;
    while (onetime==1){
        for(i = 0; i < number; i++){
            random_numbers[i] = RandomNumberGenerator(i);
        }
    onetime=0;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Array : ");
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++){
        printf("  %d ",random_numbers[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<number;i++){
        insert(&root, random_numbers[i]);
    }

    printf("tree\n");
    printElements(root);    
    islem=menu(1);
    while(islem!=0){
        tmp = search(&root, islem);
        if (tmp)
        {
        printf("Searched node=%d\n", tmp->data);
        for(i = 0; i < number; i++){
            if(random_numbers[i]==islem){
                pos=i+1;
                for(i=pos-1; i<number-1; i++)
                {
                    random_numbers[i] = random_numbers[i + 1];
                }
                number--;
                printf("Node found and deleted\n");
                islem=0;
                main();
            }
        }
}
        else
        {
            printf("Couldnt find node.\n");
            islem=menu(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is a bug in your code. But if you don't post the code, we can't help you.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i didnt want to post it because its too long but i edited

Comment: in general, NEVER call the `main()` function from your code

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently indent your code. (the compiler does not care, but us humans that read the code do.)  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: @user3629249 Its because of my lack of knowledge,i cant bend the code at my will so i needed to call main function.Even though i find a way thank you for advices i will keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when compiling, always enable the warnings.  Then fix those warnings.

The OPs posted code causes the compiler to output:

```
gcc   -O1  -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic   -c "untitled2.c"  -I. (in directory: /home/richard/Documents/forum)
untitled2.c: In function ‘RandomNumberGenerator’:
untitled2.c:119:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int i,out;
         ^
untitled2.c:117:31: warning: unused parameter ‘value’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int RandomNumberGenerator(int value)
                               ^~~~~
untitled2.c: In function ‘menu’:
untitled2.c:124:14: warning: unused parameter ‘islem’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int menu(int islem){
              ^~~~~
untitled2.c: At top level:
untitled2.c:140:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main()
      ^~~~
untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled2.c:142:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘time’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     srand(time(NULL));
           ^~~~
untitled2.c:142:11: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
untitled2.c: In function ‘search’:
untitled2.c:55:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
untitled2.c: In function ‘menu’:
untitled2.c:129:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     scanf("%d",&secim);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
untitled2.c:132:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
         scanf("%d",&sil);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Note: the *Compilation finished successfully.* just means the compiler used some 'workaround' for the problems in the code, NOT that the correct code was generated.

This warning: *untitled2.c:61:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*  is critical

regarding:

```
            number--;
            printf( "Node found and deleted\n" );
            islem = 0;
            main(  );
        }
    }
}
```

That last closing brace '}' ends the function, all all the following code of `main()` will never be executed

regarding:

```
while ( onetime  ==  1 )
{
    for( i  =  0; i < number; i++ )
    {
        random_numbers[i]  =  RandomNumberGenerator( i );
    }
    onetime = 0;
}
```

the `while()` loop will only be executed once, so why have the loop?  Suggest:

```
if ( onetime  ==  1 )
{
    for( i  =  0; i < number; i++ )
    {
        random_numbers[i]  =  RandomNumberGenerator( i );
    }
    onetime = 0;
}
```

regarding the function:

```
int menu( int islem )
```

the past in parameter is not used.  So why have it?  Suggest:

```
int menu( void )
```

and change all calls to `menu()` to not pass in a parameter

Comment: Thank you for i enabled and i will try to solve them